# Scala : Transforming a List into a nested Map

Tags: java, scala

I have an ConfigEntry class defined as

```java
case class ConfigEntry(
  key:    String,
  value:  String
)
```

and a list:

```java
val list: List[ConfigEntry] = List(
  ConfigEntry("general.first", "general first value"),
  ConfigEntry("general.second", "general second value"),
  ConfigEntry("custom.first", "custom first value"),
  ConfigEntry("custom.second", "custom second value")
)
```

Given a list of ConfigEntry, I want a map from property -> map of entries that satisfy that property

As an example, if I have

```java
def getConfig: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = {

  def getKey(key: String, index: Int): String = key.split("\\.")(index)

  list.map { config =>
    getKey(config.key, 0) -> Map(getKey(config.key, 1) -> config.value)
  }.toMap

}
```

I get result

```java
res0: Map[String,Map[String,String]] =
  Map(
    "general" ->
      Map("second" -> "general second value"),
    "custom" ->
      Map("second" -> "custom second value")
  )
```

and it should be

```java
res0: Map[String,Map[String,String]] =
Map(
  "general" ->
    Map(
      "first" -> "general first value",
      "second" -> "general second value"
    ),
  "custom" ->
    Map(
      "first" -> "custom first value",
      "second" -> "custom second value"
    )
)
```

The first record from the list is missing. It's probably through **.toMap**

How can I do this?

Thank you for any help given

Comment: There will always be two and only two parts of the key? Thus, it will always be a `Map[String, Map[String, String]]`? Or can it be infinitely nested?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
final case class ConfigEntry(
    key:    String,
    value:  String
)

type Config =  Map[String, Map[String, String]]

def getConfig(data: List[ConfigEntry]): Config =
  data
    .view
    .map(e => e.key.split('.').toList -> e.value)
    .collect {
      case (k1 :: k2 :: Nil, v) => k1 -> (k2 -> v)
    }.groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
    .view
    .mapValues(_.toMap)
    .toMap
```

Or something like this:

```
def getConfig(data: List[ConfigEntry]): Config = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[ConfigEntry], acc: Config): Config =
    remaining match {
      case ConfigEntry(key, value) :: xs =>
        val newAcc = key.split('.').toList match {
          case k1 :: k2 :: Nil =>
            acc.updatedWith(k1) {
              case Some(map) =>
                val newMap = map.updatedWith(k2) {
                  case Some(v) =>
                    println(s"Overwriting previous value ${v} for the key: ${key}")
                    // Just overwrite the previous value.
                    Some(value)

                  case None =>
                    Some(value)
                }
                Some(newMap)

              case None =>
                Some(Map(k2 -> value))
            }

          case _ =>
            println(s"Bad key: ${key}")
            // Just skip this key.
            acc
        }
        loop(remaining = xs, newAcc)

      case Nil =>
        acc
    }

  loop(remaining = data, acc = Map.empty)
}
```

I leave the handling of errors like duplicated keys or bad keys to the reader.

---

*BTW, since this is a config, have you considered using a Config library?*

Answer (score 2):

Your map will only produce a 1 to 1 result. To do what you want you will need an accumulator (existing map) to do this.

Working with your existing code, if you're especially tied to how you're parsing your primary and secondary keys via getKey you can apply foldLeft to your list instead, with an empty map as an initial value.

```
list.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Map[String, String]]) { (configs, configEntry) =>
  val primaryKey = getKey(configEntry.key, 0)
  val secondaryKey = getKey(configEntry.key, 1)

  configs.get(primaryKey) match {
    case None =>
      configs.updated(primaryKey, Map(secondaryKey -> configEntry.value))
    case Some(configMap) =>
      configs.updated(primaryKey, configMap.updated(secondaryKey, configEntry.value))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
list.map { ce =>
  val Array(l, r) = ce.key.split("\\.")
  l -> (r -> ce.value)
}                                                 // List[(String, (String, String))]
.groupBy { case (k, _) => k }                     // Map[String, List[(String, (String, String))]]
.view.mapValues(_.map { case (_, v) => v }.toMap) // MapView[String, List[(String, String)]]
.toMap                                            // Map[String, Map[String, String]]
```